# "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" when calling $.ajax jquery function

Tags: jquery, ajax

Following code block intends to collect data from the Datatable called **materialsInMaterialsRecieved** and a form called **materials-recieved** and create an object as below sample.

```
{
    PurchaseOrderId: "1",
    ReceivedDate: "07/23/2016",
    MaterialsInMaterialsRecived: {
        Cost: "2",
        MaterialId: "1",
        MaterialName: "Silk",
        QuantityDispatched: "2",
        QuantityRecieved: "2",
        Remark: "asda"
    }
}
```

This object is being created and stored as `submitData`. `submitData` needs to be sent over ajax to an API url. But when doing so, an error is thrown which says     `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.`

Following is the html markup,

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <form action="/api/MaterialsRecieveds/AddMaterialsRecieved" id="materials-recieved" method="POST">
        <div id="name-group" class="form-group">

            <label for="name">Purchase OrderID</label>
            <select name="PurchaseOrderId" class="form-control" id="PurchaseOrderList"></select>

            <label for="date">P/O sent time</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ReceivedDate" id="receivedDate">
        </div>
    </form>
        <button class="btn btn-success" id="create-materials-recieved-note">Create Materials Recieved Note</button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <table id="materials-in-materials-recieved" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Material Id</th>
                <th>Material Name</th>
                <th>Quantity Recieved</th>
                <th>Quantity Dispatched</th>
                <th>Cost</th>
                <th>Remarks</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Following is the javacript code,

```
    $("#create-materials-recieved-note").on('click',function (event) {
        var submitData = {};
        var materials = materialsInMaterialsRecieved.rows().data(); // materialsInMaterialsRecieved is a handle for a Datatable

        $("#materials-recieved .form-control").each(function () {
            submitData[$(this).attr2("name")] = $(this).val();

        })

        submitData["MaterialsInMaterialsRecived"] = materials;
        console.log(submitData);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post', // define the type of http verb we want to use (post for our form)
            url: '/api/MaterialsRecieveds/AddMaterialsRecieved', // the url where we want to post
            data: submitData, // our data object
            dataType: 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
            contentType: 'application/json',      
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

If I comment-out the $.ajax(... statement then the error doesn't appear.

Comment: Why did you specify content type of `application/json` when you are sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? Also `datatype` should be `dataType` if you want to have any effect.

Comment: Capitalization error at `datatype` and encoding removed.

Comment: Well you are still specifying `application/json` content type which is wrong because that's not what you are sending. If you want to send JSON payload then do so: `data: JSON.stringify(submitData)`. Otherwise get rid of this `contentType` parameter.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`submitData` is a huge array-like-object. If I pass `submitData` directly into the `$.ajax` JQuery tries to serialize payload data into a json, because I have given dataType as 'json'.  This JQuery serialization creates lots of method callbacks and freezes the browser, then throws the error notifying it.

The simple solution to this problem was avoiding JQuery serialization and passing a stringified version of the payload data to the ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post', 
    url: '/api/MaterialsRecieveds/AddMaterialsRecieved', 
    data: JSON.stringify(submitData), // stringyfy before passing
    dataType: 'json', // payload is json
    contentType : 'application/json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case and similar code, JSON related

> "uncaught range error maximum call stack..."

error was resolved by making sure I don't have cycling events like one button triggering another which then triggers first button on click etc..

And by making sure I've added

```
return false;
```

after every on click event/trigger...

So, for example my table row -  click event which triggers radio buttons to be checked now looks like this:

```
$("tr").click(function(){
  $(this).find("input").prop("checked", true).trigger("click");
  return false;
});
```

While my radio buttons look like this:

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
    var customer = $.parseJSON($(this).val());
  $("#customer_id").val(customer.id);
    $("#company_name").val(customer.company_name);
    $("#contact_info").val(customer.contact_info);
  return false;
});
```

And without return false, this code causes the above mentioned error...

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue and it was because I was sending a jQuery object in the data rather than a string like I meant to:

```
$( '#email-signup-form' ).on( 'submit', function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const form = $( this );
    // Error here:
    const email = $( '[name="email"]', form ); // Should be: $( '[name="email"]', form ).val();

    form.addClass( 'submitting' );

    $.ajax( {
        method: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: ajaxURL,
        data: {
            action: 'email_signup',
            email: email,
        },
        success: function( res ) {
            if ( res && res.success === true ) {
                //
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            //
        },
    } );
} );
```